# Trying to prove an inequality involving sum and logrithms

Tags: calculus, probability, inequality

I am trying to prove one thing even though I know that's true but I am unable to form a formal argument for instance I am trying to prove

$$\sum_{i=1}^n {c_{i} \over n} \log_{2}(c_i) \ge 0 $$

where $\sum_{i=1}^n {c_{i} \over n} = 1$ and also $c_{i}\ge 0$. Also $0\cdot\log_{2}(0) = 0$ as

$$\lim_{x \to 0} x\log_{2}x = 0$$

Here neither I can find any counter example. So somehow I am actually kind of sure that the above inequality holds but I am not sure what is the formal argument for that.

Please help

Ahsan

Comment: I assume you're defining $0 \cdot \log_2(0) = 0$?

Comment: @Tom yes you are right I edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = x\log x$, we have $f''(x) = \frac{1}{x}, x>0$, so $f(x)$ is convex, which means

$$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(c_i) \geq f(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nc_i)$$

and $f(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nc_i) = f(1) = 0$

As @Henry pointed out, we also need $\log_2 c_i = \dfrac{\log c_i}{\log 2}$ to conclude.

Since it's tagged probability, let's remark that it's Jensen's inequality $E(f(X)) \geq f(EX)$ for $f(x) = x\log_2 x$ and $X$ taking value among all the $c_i$ with equal probability $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: +1.  Pedantically, log base $2$ in the question, rather than base $e$, though it only multiplies the second derivative by a positive constant

Comment: @Henry Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle just one more thing regarding last line so if we have all $c_{i}$ with different probability then this doesn't work?

Comment: @AhsanIqbal It could still work, since as long as $EX=1$, we have $f(EX) = 0$. But of course the expression of $E(f(X))$ need to be modified according to the new probability

Answer (score 0):

By logarithmic inequality for $c_{i}>0$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n {c_{i} \over n} \log_{2}(c_i) \geq \sum_{i=1}^n {c_{i} \over n}\frac{c_{i}-1}{c_{i}}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{c_{i}-1}{n}=1-1=0 $$